# Good training on the model reports bad results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have this dataset of Images belonging to 6 classes. I have split the data into training and testing set with a test size of 10%. I use `ImageDataGenerator` for the purpose of loading and augmenting my data. Here I create 2 generators. One for training and one for validation which is a subset of the training data.

```
# Create train_generator

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,  # Path to data
    target_size=(30, 30),  # Average target size (32 + 28)/2 = 30
    batch_size=32,  # Batch size
    class_mode='categorical',  # Categorical Class mode
    classes=classes,  # Classes
    subset='training',  # Training Subset
    color_mode='grayscale'
)
```

```
# Create validation_generator

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,  # Path to data
    target_size=(30, 30),  # Average target size
    batch_size=16,  # Batch Size
    class_mode='categorical',  # Categorical Class mode
    classes=classes,  # Classes
    subset='validation',  # Validation Subset
    color_mode='grayscale'
)
```

Now I have trained a simple self-made model for 100 epochs.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 128)       1280      
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 28, 28, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 32)          18464     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 4, 4, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 774       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 6)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 110,822
Trainable params: 110,822
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The history of the training went like this. 
[image: Training Results]

After that, I create a test generator like

```
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(
    test_path,  # Path to data
    target_size=(30, 30),  # Average target size (32 + 28)/2 = 30
    batch_size=32,  # Batch size
    class_mode='categorical',  # Categorical Class mode
    classes=classes,  # Classes
    color_mode='grayscale'
)
```

I make predictions using this generator

```
#Confution Matrix and Classification Report
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator, test_generator.n // test_generator.batch_size+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
```

Now when I make confusion matrix and classification report using these predictions, I get very bad results.

```
Confusion Matrix:

[[166  31   1 140 135 152]
 [ 33   4   0  20  25  27]
 [ 17   1   0  10  11  10]
 [130  25   1 111 115 142]
 [126  17   2 107  81 124]
 [153  24   1 141 129 159]]
```

```
Classification Report:

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         Bag       0.27      0.27      0.27       625
      Sandal       0.04      0.04      0.04       109
  automobile       0.00      0.00      0.00        49
        bird       0.21      0.21      0.21       524
       truck       0.16      0.18      0.17       457
  Ankle boot       0.26      0.26      0.26       607

    accuracy                           0.22      2371
   macro avg       0.16      0.16      0.16      2371
weighted avg       0.22      0.22      0.22      2371
```

Can you please guide me for if im doing something wrong or guide me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Not a full answer, but the fact that your accuracy/loss are deteriorating on the test set(s) strongly indicates overfitting of the model. Depending on the architecture and dataset, 100 epochs is often excessive.

Comment: I can experiment with early stopping. But earlier this morning I trained the model for only 10 epochs and there was no overfitting at all. But the model was still performing worse on the data.

Comment: I suppose the class order may be changing in the new generator? Or you forgot a certain preprocessing that is in `train_generator` but not in the new generator?